# Switch between reference and value preview of string resources in the xml editor

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-resources

when working in Android Studio in xml values and referencing to `@Strings/xy` for instance, I have seen in a video, that it is actually possible to display the actual values directly in the same editor window. It was **basically a switch to between `@String/xy` and "XYContent", but with the reference still existing.**

I am not referencing to "ctrl+click" which opens (in my case) the `strings.xml` in a new tab.

Any idea? Couldn't find any reference to this in the help file.

Comment: Your question in not clear. Be more specific

Comment: Do you want to see the preview of String value?

Comment: yes i want to see the preview of the actual value

Answer (score 24):

Click and **bring the cursor to the string resource reference** and press **`Ctrl`+`-`** (**Cmd** for Mac, minus/hyphen) and you'll see the preview.

It basically does a collapse all for the code and collapsed string resource references show the values as preview. Collapse all action can also be done from the menu if you are comfortable with mouse more than keyboard. `Right-Click -> Folding > Collapse`

To switch back press **`Ctrl`+`+`** (**Cmd** for Mac) with the cursor still on same reference.

Comment: Worked. Just noting use `Cmd+'-'` for Mac. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can go to `Preferences => Appearance & Behavior => Editor => General => Code Folding` and enable `Android String References` to always see the value of string resource in the java file.